# Color changing in windows ping

Tags: windows, batch-file, ping

Does anyone know how to make windows pinger (.bat) to show normally green but when and only when the target of the ping is offline the color is red? I have tried this several times and never got it to work. The current script is down below. That one does not work it will just change colord rapidly.

````
:top
PING -n 1 %IP% | FIND "TTL="
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (SET in=0b & color 04 & echo Connection timed out.) 
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO color
REM errorhandling, errorlevel >= 1
ping -t 2 0 10 127.0.0.1 >nul
GoTo top
:color
color 02
GoTo top```
````

Comment: Try out this old batch file : [Multi Ping Tester with colors](https://pastebin.com/zjYwSqUM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for testing :

```bat
@echo off
REM https://pastebin.com/zjYwSqUM
Title Multi-Ping hosts Tester with colors updated on 2021 by Hackoo
call :init
set "URLS=%~dp0URLS.txt"
If Not exist "%URLS%" goto CreateDummyFile
mode con cols=70 lines=35
set "LogFile=PingResults.txt"
If exist "%LogFile%" Del "%LogFile%"
echo(
call :color 0E "      ------- Ping status of targets hosts -------" 1
echo(
(
    echo ******************************************************
    echo   PingTest executed on %Date% @ Time %Time%
    echo ******************************************************
    echo(
) > %LogFile%
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%URLS%") do (
    Call :StringFormat "%%a"
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%b in ('ping -n 1 !URL!') do set "ip=%%b"
        ping -n 1 !URL!>nul && set "msg=!URL! - !ip! ALive ok" && Call :Color 0A "     !msg!" 1 || set "msg=!URL! - !ip! Dead failed to respond" && Call :Color 0C "     !msg!" 1
        echo !msg! >> %LogFile%
    )
)
EndLocal
Start "" "%LogFile%" & TimeOut /T 5 /Nobreak>nul & exit
::************************************************************************************* 
:init
prompt $g
for /F "delims=." %%a in ('"prompt $H. & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"
exit /b
::*************************************************************************************
:color
set nL=%3
if not defined nL echo requires third argument & pause > nul & goto :eof
if %3 == 0 (
    <nul set /p ".=%bs%">%2 & findstr /v /a:%1 /r "^$" %2 nul & del %2 2>&1 & goto :eof
) else if %3 == 1 (
    echo %bs%>%2 & findstr /v /a:%1 /r "^$" %2 nul & del %2 2>&1 & goto :eof
)
exit /b
::*************************************************************************************
:ReplaceString <Data> <String1> <String2>
(
    echo Wscript.echo Replace("%~1","%~2","%~3"^)
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"') do ( set "URL=%%a" )
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
exit /b
::*************************************************************************************
:StringFormat <URL>
(   
    echo Function StringReplace(Str^)
    echo    Str = Replace(Str,"http://",""^)
    echo    Str = Replace(Str,"https://",""^)
    echo    StringReplace = str
    echo End Function
    echo wscript.echo StringReplace("%~1"^)
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"') do ( set "URL=%%a" )
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
exit /b
::*************************************************************************************
:CreateDummyFile
(
    echo http://www.hyperdebrid.com
    echo http://www.fakirdebrid.net
    echo http://www.keepfiles.fr
    echo http://www.4shared.com 
    echo https://1fichier.com
    echo http://www.mega.co.nz
    echo http://www.mediafire.com
    echo http://www.uploaded.net
    echo http://www.oboom.com
    echo http://www.letitbit.net
    echo http://www.keep2share.cc
    echo http://alfafile.net
    echo https://www.bigfile.to
    echo http://www.dailymotion.com
    echo http://www.datafile.com
    echo http://www.Depfile.com
    echo http://www.Dropbox.com
    echo http://www.Extmatrix.com
    echo http://www.Fboom.me
    echo http://www.Filefactory.com
    echo http://www.Filesmonster.com
    echo http://www.Fshare.vn
    echo http://www.Keep2share.com
    echo http://www.Mega.nz
    echo http://www.Rapidgator.net
    echo http://www.Scribd.com
    echo http://www.Soundcloud.com
    echo http://www.Speedyshare.com
    echo http://www.Turbobit.net
    echo http://www.Vimeo.com
 )>%URLS%
start /b "" cmd /c "%~f0" & exit
::*************************************************************************************
```

---

***EDIT : on 22/01/2021 @ 12:53***

```bat
@echo off
Title IP Pinger with color by Hackoo 2021
:Main
cls & echo(
echo Type the IP address for checking
Set /P "IP="
call :init
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
ping -n 1 !IP! |find /I "TTL">nul && set "msg=!IP! - ALive ok" && ( 
    Call :Color 0A "!msg!" 1
 ) || (
    set "msg=!IP! - Dead - Failed to respond" && Call :Color 0C "!msg!" 1
)
echo(
echo Hit any key to check another IP address !
Pause>nul & goto Main
::------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:init
prompt $g
for /F "delims=." %%a in ('"prompt $H. & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"
exit /b
::------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:color
set nL=%3
if not defined nL echo requires third argument & pause > nul & goto :eof
if %3 == 0 (
    <nul set /p ".=%bs%">%2 & findstr /v /a:%1 /r "^$" %2 nul & del %2 2>&1 & goto :eof
) else if %3 == 1 (
    echo %bs%>%2 & findstr /v /a:%1 /r "^$" %2 nul & del %2 2>&1 & goto :eof
)
exit /b
::------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is very good script. However the problem is that it will ping websites that are already in the file. The point of the pinger is that i can choose ipv4 address to ping. So with that script the whole idea of the pinger is useless. However really nice script with good concept.

Comment: @Monder Did you mean that the ipv4 is stored in a text file like `192.168.1.2 ...`

Comment: Nope. I want it to work like this. `set /p IP=Enter ip :` and after that.
`PING -n 1 %IP% | FIND "TTL="`
`IF ERRORLEVEL 1`
You don't need to use exact same syntax but that is how i did it.

Comment: @Monder Please Check the new code edited and tell the results !

Comment: This is perfect. Its not what i was looking for but i think its even better. Thanks for this script it was really helpful !

Comment: @Monder don't forget to mark it as an answer so !

Answer (score 0):

Achieved with the below

```
cls
echo off
:top
PING -n 1 %1 | FIND "TTL="
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    SET in=0b
    color 04 
    echo Connection timed out.
    GOTO top
) else (
    GOTO color
)
GoTo top
:color
color 02
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul
GoTo top
```

Comment: For me it will just show red color and the "connection timed out" text even when the target of the ping is online.

Comment: Interesting... seems to work for me.
[link](https://giphy.com/gifs/BVGwVFdy4XtG2Vovan)

Answer (score 0):

Theres many approaches you can take for this task

The two main components of the task are:

- 1. effecting a means of conditional execution based on success or failure.

  - `&&` can be used to execute a command if the previous command on the same line was succesful.
  - `||` Can be used to execute a command if the previous command failed / did not execute.
- 2. Coloring text output

  - Findstr can be used to read a filename and display it using hex color values. This can be used for printing strings by creating filenames with text matching the string you wish to output, provided the characters in the string aren't invalid for use in filenames.

Here's an example that uses these two main points to effect the desired output:

```bat
@Echo off
rem /* Macro Definitions */
 For /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (set "DEL=%%a")
rem /* %\C% - Color macro; No error checking. Usage:
::: %\C:?=HEXVALUE%Output String
::: Concatenated: (%\C:?=HEXVALUE%Output String) & (%\C:?=HEXVALUE%Output String)
::: Concatenated during conditional execution: ((%\C:?=HEXVALUE%Output String) & (%\C:?=HEXVALUE%Output String))
rem To force a new line; terminate an output string with \n */
 Set "\C=For %%o in (1 2)Do if %%o==2 (( <nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "^^!os:\n=^^!" ) & ( findstr /v /a:? /R "^$" "^^!os:\n=^^!" nul ) & ( del "^^!os:\n=^^!" > nul 2>&1 ) & (If not "^^!os:\n=^^!" == "^^!os^^!" (Echo/)))Else Set os="
rem /* Ensure macro escaping is correct depending on delayedexpansion environment type */
 If Not "!![" == "[" (
  Set "\C=%\C:^^=^%"
 )

::: SCRIPT MAIN BODY

Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
 PUSHD "%~dp0"
 ping -n 1 www.google.com | find "TTL" > nul && ((%\C:?=20%www.google.com)&(%\C:?=02% online\n)) || ((%\C:?=40%www.google.com)&(%\C:?=04% offline\n))
 ping -n 1 www.googlefalse.com | find "TTL" > nul && ((%\C:?=20%www.googlefalse.com)&(%\C:?=02% online\n)) || ((%\C:?=40%www.googlefalse.com)&(%\C:?=04% offline\n))
 POPD
 Endlocal
Goto :Eof
```

Comment: Hmm can you explain how i should use those if i want it to work? I tried those like this.

`title Test pinger
echo off & cls
color 02
set /p IP=Enter ip :
:top
PING -n 1 %IP% | FIND "TTL="
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (SET in=0b & color 04 & echo Connection timed out.) 
|| color 02
ping -t 2 0 10 127.0.0.1 >nul
GoTo top`

But it will just close instantly.

Comment: Please do not post multiple lines of code in a comment - Any formatting is lost rendering it impossible to tell if you have used linebreaks appropriately in your code. Instead, update your question with the new minimal reproduceable code and use a comment to draw attention  to the change. I'd suggest you follow the syntax I exampled, where `&&` is used on the same line after `FIND` to execute commands on success, and `||` follows on the same line to execute commands on failure. Note also the use of parentheses to mark code blocks when multiple commands are concatenated between conditions.